# IOS Subview displaying but not loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I'm implementing a cordova subview in my view controller using the following code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CDVViewController* viewController = [CDVViewController new];
    viewController.wwwFolderName = @"www";
    viewController.startPage = @"index.html";
    viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 450);
    [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
}
```

For some reason the subview is getting added, but my content isn't loading, instead all I see is a black page. I was getting an error saying it could not find the assets to load, but I resolved that by adding the folder to the project.

My suspicion is that I have used this line incorrectly to reference my view controller:

```
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
```

The documentation says to do this :

```
[myView addSubview:viewController.view];
```

As you can see I replaced myView with self.view because myView wasn't defined.

Anyone know how to resolve this?

[image]

What is loading. Note the ViewController's normal background is white, so I know the subview is loading.

Comment: [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
after this line call the method [viewController loadContent]; // loadContent should be custom method in which u will initialize or load the data...

Comment: What is your subview's content? Where did you load it in your subview? From the init method? awakeFromNib method? or from drawRect?

Comment: Make sure that your view is linked up in the storyboard, and created in the .H file. If you are not using the storyboard then you have to create a new view above this and then you can add the new view to the view controller.

Comment: I am using a storyboard how do I link it in the .h file

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to link via Interface Builder

1. either you simply drag n drop new uiview on viewController and rightclick on view and link referencing outlets to File's Owner view
2. In you .h file IBOutlet UIView* myView; and link it with your File's Owner view

Comment: I did this and now I can get javascript from the Subview to load (tested an alert), however the view still appears just black! What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

u sure your background color of the view is not black.

if it is underneath the view then you can bring it front by [self bringSubViewToFront:(yourviewname)];